# Eventos VBA no PowerPoint

Tags: vba, eventos, slide, inicialização, powerpoint

Olá,

Exite algum evento no Powerpoint que permita a execução de uma subrotina ao selecionar um slide.

Por exemplo, a apresentação esta correndo... Quando chegar no slide 120 ele tem que executar uma rotina ou uma macro sem nenhuma ação do usuário ou botão.

Busquei algo como: slide120_Open() e slide120_Iniciallize() mas não obtive sucesso em nenhum dos dois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Evento

Para acionar alguma programação quando o Slide do Powerpoint atingir/chegar numa determinada página durante a apresentação, o evento `OnSlideShowPageChange` pode ser usado.

O código será chamado antes de entrar no Slide, durante a transição.

Por exemplo, o código será chamado no Slide 3: `Slide 2 -> Transição -> Slide 3`.

### Código

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
   'O Slide 3 é selecionado
   If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 3 Then
       'Créditos https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205576/7690982
       'Inserir o código aqui.
       MsgBox "Teste: O código foi acionado."
   EndIf
End Sub
```